# Summarize categorical variables by numeric: gtsummary package

Tags: r, gtsummary

I need help on how to write R code using gtsummary package to create a summary table with several categorical variables as rows and the column side (the "by" variable) is a numeric variable in my case, age in years. So in essence I would like to summarize several patient categorical characteristics by their mean/median age.

As an example, in this package, with the data "trial", I would like for instance to have on the row axis of the table the categorical variables (marker, stage, grade) while the by variable is "age", so median age for each category of those variables.

Thank you for help.
Nelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% clear on what you're asking.  I am guessing you want to summarize data by high age and low age (split at the median in the example below)?

First, you will want to create a categorical age variable.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

df_age_example <-
  trial %>%
  mutate(
    # create a categorical age variable split at the median
    age2 = ifelse(
      age >= median(.$age, na.rm = TRUE),
      "Age Above or at Median",
      "Age Below Median"
    )
  ) %>%
  # keep variables to be summarized 
  select(age2, marker, grade)
```

Then you'll want to pass that data frame to `tbl_summary()` to summarize the data.

```r
tbl_summary(data= df_age_example, by = age2)
```

That will yield the table below.

[image]

I hope this helps. Happy Coding!

Comment: Apologies I was not clear Daniel. I would like to calculate the average/mean age based on the levels of other variables.
For example, to report the average age for Grade I = 59, Grade II = 65, Grade III = 69 years and so forth.
Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, I see!  In that case, you'd want something like this:
trial %>%
  select(age, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = grade, statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean}")

There is not a way to do this in a long table with multiple categorical variables as the rows using the gtsummary package, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old question, I though it was worth noting (for future readers) that gtsummary currently has a `tbl_custom_summary()` function which does make this possible:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

my_fn <- function(data, full_data, variable, by, type, ...) {
  mean_age <- mean(data$age, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(1) %>% format(nsmall = 1)
  age_sd <- sd(data$age, na.rm = TRUE) %>% round(1) %>% format(nsmall = 1)
  tibble(age = paste0(mean_age, " (", age_sd, ")"))
}

trial %>%
  select(c(grade, trt, stage, age, response)) %>%
  mutate(response = factor(response)) %>%
  tbl_custom_summary(
    by = response,
  stat_fns = all_categorical() ~ my_fn,
  statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{age}",
  include = c(grade, trt, stage)
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great @ZKA . FYI there is now a function called tbl_continuous() in the package that does just this in case it's helpful for you in the future

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Goodness, that's way better! Thanks for letting me know!